# Android Speed From Satellite Accuracy

Tags: android, performance, gps, location

I am using the gps manager in Android to obtain Location objects for information about the user's location.  I noticed there is a function to get the user's speed in m/s: Location.getSpeed().

Assuming my location is very accurate (<10m), how accurate can I expect Location.getSpeed() to be?

Note: I noticed there was a method called getAccuracy() and I wasn't sure if this could help me tell how accurate the speed was or if it only applied to the actual location(latitude and longitude).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on your hardware and the no. of visible satellites. I am using the speed from the location object to determine aircraft speed to detect events like take-off or landing in a flight logger application. The accuracy is sufficient for that, probably accurate within one or two knots (1.85 to 3.7 km/h).

If the user is walking I would expect less accuracy in relation to his or her absolute speed value.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy of GPS speed is not directly dependent on the position accuracy, because many of the errors in position are systematic. Very nearly the same error will apply to two sequential position calculations. So, although the positions are inaccurate by (say) 5 metres, the speed and direction between the two will still be calculated accurately.

As per the previous answer, my experience has been that speed is typically accurate to about 1-5kph.